# Matching Sinon FakeXMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, sinon

I am running Sinon's fake XMLHttpRequest function and I am not able to match the results in my test when checking with `calledWith`.

Test - partially taken from docs:

```
// New spy callback and make our call
var callback = sinon.spy();
myLib.getCommentsFor("/some/article", callback);

// Add a response to our request that we stored in `beforeEach` 
this.requests[0].respond(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                            '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]');

// Check - both of these fail
assert(callback.calledWith([{ id: 12, comment: "Hey there" }])); 
assert(callback.calledWith({ key: '12' ));
```

If I dump `callback.getCall(0).args[0]` I get this object:

```
FakeXMLHttpRequest {
  readyState: 4,
  requestHeaders: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' },
  requestBody: { key: '12' },
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  upload:
   UploadProgress {
     eventListeners: { progress: [], load: [], abort: [], error: [] } },
  responseType: '',
  response: '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]',
  eventListeners:
   { loadend: [ [Function] ],
     abort: [ [Function] ],
     load: [ [Function] ],
     loadstart: [ [Function] ] },
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000',
  async: true,
  username: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  responseText: '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]',
  responseXML: null,
  sendFlag: true,
  onreadystatechange: [Function],
  errorFlag: false,
  responseHeaders: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
```

My internal code is the one sending the `{ key: '12' }` request. I am not sure what calledWith is really referring to so I tried testing for both response and request but both fail.

Any idea why it's failing - how can I tell what it is actually being "called with"?

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved. My callback method was returning the entire `xhr` object and the examples assume you are only returning `xhr.response`.